# How to prevent from the changing the selected color when we are refreshing the browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

sorry for my English..

In my website i added some colors to change the colors of my website based on selected color.. it is working good.

but the problem is when i refresh the window it shows the default color but i want to show selected color when browser refreshed also..

Thanks in advance..!

I am eegarly waiting for your response.

```js
    function openNav() {
        document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "270px";
    }
    
    function closeNav() {
        document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
    }
    
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#content-width").click(function () {
            $("#content").css({
                "width": "900px",
                "margin": "auto",
                "border": "1px solid #ddd",
                "background-color": "white"
                
            });
            $("#myMap").css({
                "width": "370px",
                "height": "300px",            
    
            });
            $(".navbar-expand-md .navbar-nav .nav-link").css({
                "padding-right": "2.6rem",
                "padding-left": "2.6rem"
            });
            $("body").css("background-color","#f2f2f2");
        });
        $("#original").click(function () {
            $(".index_top,.about-text,.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link:focus, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .active > .nav-link, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link.active, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link.show, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .show > .nav-link,.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link:focus, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .active > .nav-link, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link.active, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link.show, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .show > .nav-link").css("background-color", "#2a3637");
            $("#nav").css("border-bottom", "5px solid #2a3637");
            $("#logo_img").attr("src", "images/logo.png");
            $(".for-bold-text").css("color", "#2a3637");
            $("#content").css({
                "width": "auto",
                "margin": "auto",
                "border": "none",
                "background-color": "white"
            });
            $("#myMap").css({
                "width": "500px",
                "height": "400px",
    
            });
            $(".navbar-expand-md .navbar-nav .nav-link").css({
                "padding-right": "4.25rem",
                "padding-left": "4.25rem"
            });
            $("body").css("background-color", "#fff");
        });
    
        $("#red").click(function () {
            $(".index_top,.about-text,.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link:focus, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .active > .nav-link, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link.active, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link.show, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .show > .nav-link,.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link:focus, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .active > .nav-link, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link.active, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link.show, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .show > .nav-link").css("background-color", "#60100b");
            $("#nav").css("border-bottom", "5px solid #60100b");
            $("#logo_img").attr("src", "images/logo_red.png");
            $(".for-bold-text").css("color", "#60100b");
        });
    
        $("#blue").click(function () {
            $(".index_top,.about-text,.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link:focus, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .active > .nav-link, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link.active, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link.show, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .show > .nav-link,.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link:focus, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .active > .nav-link, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link.active, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link.show, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .show > .nav-link").css("background-color", "#012A59");
            $("#nav").css("border-bottom", "5px solid #012A59");
            $("#logo_img").attr("src", "images/logo_blue.png");
            $(".for-bold-text").css("color", "#012A59");
        });
    
        $("#green").click(function () {
            $(".index_top,.about-text,.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link:focus, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .active > .nav-link, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link.active, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link.show, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .show > .nav-link,.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link:focus, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .active > .nav-link, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link.active, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link.show, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .show > .nav-link").css("background-color", "#41564a");
            $("#nav").css("border-bottom", "5px solid #41564a");
            $("#logo_img").attr("src", "images/logo_green.png");
            $(".for-bold-text").css("color", "#41564a");
        });
    
        $("#yellow").click(function () {
            $(".index_top,.about-text,.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link:focus, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .active > .nav-link, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link.active, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link.show, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .show > .nav-link,.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link:focus, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .active > .nav-link, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link.active, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link.show, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .show > .nav-link").css("background-color", "#586624");
            $("#nav").css("border-bottom", "5px solid #586624");
            $("#logo_img").attr("src", "images/logo_yellow.png");
            $(".for-bold-text").css("color", "#586624");
        });
    
        $("#gray").click(function () {
            $(".index_top,.about-text,.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link:focus, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .active > .nav-link, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link.active, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link.show, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .show > .nav-link,.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link:focus, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .active > .nav-link, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link.active, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link.show, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .show > .nav-link").css("background-color", "#495c5e");
            $("#nav").css("border-bottom", "5px solid #495c5e");
            $("#logo_img").attr("src", "images/logo_gray.png");
            $(".for-bold-text").css("color", "#495c5e");
        });
    
        $("#voilet").click(function () {
            $(".index_top,.about-text,.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link:focus, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .active > .nav-link, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link.active, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link.show, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .show > .nav-link,.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link:focus, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .active > .nav-link, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link.active, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link.show, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .show > .nav-link").css("background-color", "#513168");
            $("#nav").css("border-bottom", "5px solid #513168");
            $("#logo_img").attr("src", "images/logo_voilet.png");
            $(".for-bold-text").css("color", "#513168");
        });
    
        $("#black").click(function () {
            $(".index_top,.about-text,.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link:focus, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .active > .nav-link, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link.active, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link.show, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .show > .nav-link,.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link:focus, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .active > .nav-link, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link.active, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link.show, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .show > .nav-link").css("background-color", "#16627f");
            $("#nav").css("border-bottom", "5px solid #16627f");
            $("#logo_img").attr("src", "images/logo_black.png");
            $(".for-bold-text").css("color", "#16627f");
        });
    
        $("#white").click(function () {
            $(".index_top,.about-text,.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link:focus, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .active > .nav-link, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link.active, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link.show, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .show > .nav-link,.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link:focus, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .active > .nav-link, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link.active, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link.show, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .show > .nav-link").css("background-color", "#3d0d3f");
            $("#nav").css("border-bottom", "5px solid #3d0d3f");
            $("#logo_img").attr("src", "images/logo_white.png");
            $(".for-bold-text").css("color", "#3d0d3f");
        });
    
        $("#purple").click(function () {
            $(".index_top,.about-text,.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link:focus, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .active > .nav-link, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link.active, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link.show, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .show > .nav-link,.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link:focus, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .active > .nav-link, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link.active, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link.show, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .show > .nav-link").css("background-color", "#CD0674");
            $("#nav").css("border-bottom", "5px solid #CD0674");
            $("#logo_img").attr("src", "images/logo_purple.png");
            $(".for-bold-text").css("color", "#CD0674");       
        });
        
    });
```

```css
    .sidenav {
        width: 0;
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 1;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        background-color: rgb(230,240,251);
        overflow-x: hidden;
        transition: 0.5s;
        border:2px ridge #fff;
        border-radius:5px;
        box-shadow: 8px 8px 8px rgba(158,122,122,0.16);
        margin-top: 60px;
    }
    
        .sidenav a:hover {
            color: #fc0606;
        }
    
        .sidenav .closebtn {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            right: 5px;
            font-size: 36px;
           
        }
    
    .icon {
        font-size: 30px;
        cursor: pointer;
        position: fixed;
        left: 0px;
        top: 60px;
        padding: 10px;
        background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    }
    
        .icon img {
            height: 30px
        }
    
        .icon img {
            -webkit-animation: rotation 2s infinite linear;
        }
    
    @-webkit-keyframes rotation {
        from {
            -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
        }
    
        to {
            -webkit-transform: rotate(359deg);
        }
    }
    
    @media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
        .sidenav {
            padding-top: 15px;
        }
    
            .sidenav a {
                font-size: 18px;
            }
    }
    #original {
        color:forestgreen;
       text-align:center;
       font-size:20px;
       font-weight:bold;
    
    }
    #red, #blue, #green, #yellow, #gray, #voilet, #black, #white, #purple {
        height: 40px;
        width: 40px;
        float: left;
        margin: 10px;
    }
    #red {
        padding: 15px;
        background-color: #60100b;
    }
    #blue {
        padding: 15px;
        background-color: #012A59;
    }
    #green {
        padding: 15px;
        background-color: #41564a;
    }
    #yellow {
        padding: 15px;
        background-color: #586624;
    }
    #gray {
        padding: 15px;
        background-color: #495c5e;
    }
    #voilet {
        padding: 15px;
        background-color: #513168;
    }
    #black {
        padding: 15px;
        background-color: #16627f;
    }
    #white {
        padding: 15px;
        background-color: #3d0d3f;
    }
    #purple {
        padding: 15px;
        background-color: #CD0674;
    }
    
    #content-width 
    {
        text-align:center;
        font-weight:bold;
        font-size:20px;
        color:#000;
    }
    .index_top {
        background-color: #2a3637;
        height: 35px;
    }
        .index_top p 
        {
            color:#fff;
            padding-top:5px;
        }
```

```html
  
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <title>JS Bin</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    
    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    
    <!-- Popper JS -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    
    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div id="content">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="index_top">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xl-12 col-12 col-lg-12">
                            <div class="col-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-xl-6">
                                <p>
                                    <i class="fa fa-phone"></i> &nbsp; &nbsp;123456789
                                </p>
                            </div>
                           
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
    
                <!-- LOGO  IMAGE -->
                
    
    
              
                <!-- SIDE COLOR MENU -->
    
                <div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
                    <div>
                        <div id="red"></div>
                        <div id="blue"></div>
                        <div id="green"></div>
                        <div id="yellow"></div>
                        <div id="gray"></div>
                        <div id="voilet"></div>
                        <div id="black"></div>
                        <div id="white"></div>
                        <div id="purple"></div>
                        <div class="clearfix"></div>
                        <p id="original">Show Original</p>
                        <p id="content-width">Low width</p>
                    </div>
    
    
                </div>
                <span class="icon" onclick="openNav()">
                    <img src="images/tool.png" class="img-fluid" alt="open"/>
                </span>
    
    
              
    
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Unless your script store changed color values somwhere in database, and pull that value on page refresh. current scenario is expected. You need to use server side scripting to acheieve what you want. like php, asp.net etc.

Comment: Do you mean, how to store color changes made by clicking on some button?

Comment: You can use `localStorage` or `sessionStorage`.

Comment: @DheerajKumar Not really, there is also a local storage.

Comment: yes i want store it is in local storage

Comment: Tan .. Could you please help me how to use localstorage or session storage

Comment: Are you isng localStorage?

Comment: noo Dheeraj  i tried it but it doesn't work

Comment: Shalik - if your question is about an issue with using `localStorage` please update the body of the question. Currently, the question does not include relevant information about the real issue you're having.

Comment: @DheerajKumar i stored the value the in `localstorage` and called it at the top of the code
But still on refresh browser was all white
Any hints on how can i call it effectively?

Comment: It would be easier if you can share code or create a new question please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a class to the boxes so that you can significantly reduce the code. I have added the working code below, please refer it.
**HTML**

```
<div>
<div class="box" id="red"></div>
<div class="box" id="blue"></div>
<div class="box" id="green"></div>
<div class="box" id="yellow"></div>
<div class="box" id="gray"></div>
<div class="box" id="voilet"></div>
<div class="box" id="black"></div>
<div class="box" id="white"></div>
<div class="box" id="purple"></div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
<p id="original">Show Original</p>
<p id="content-width">Low width</p>
</div>
```

**Script**

```
function openNav() {
document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "270px";
}

function closeNav() {
   document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
}

$(document).ready(function () {
$(".index_top,.about-text,.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link:focus, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .active > .nav-link, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link.active, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link.show, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .show > .nav-link,.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link:focus, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .active > .nav-link, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link.active, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link.show, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .show > .nav-link").css("background-color", localStorage.getItem("default"));
$("#content-width").click(function () {
    $("#content").css({
        "width": "900px",
        "margin": "auto",
        "border": "1px solid #ddd",
        "background-color": "white"

    });
    $("#myMap").css({
        "width": "370px",
        "height": "300px",            

    });
    $(".navbar-expand-md .navbar-nav .nav-link").css({
        "padding-right": "2.6rem",
        "padding-left": "2.6rem"
    });
    $("body").css("background-color",localStorage.getItem("default"));
});
$("#original").click(function () {
    $(".index_top,.about-text,.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link:focus, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .active > .nav-link, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link.active, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link.show, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .show > .nav-link,.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link:focus, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .active > .nav-link, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link.active, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link.show, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .show > .nav-link").css("background-color", "#2a3637");
    $("#nav").css("border-bottom", "5px solid #2a3637");
    $("#logo_img").attr("src", "images/logo.png");
    $(".for-bold-text").css("color", "#2a3637");
    $("#content").css({
        "width": "auto",
        "margin": "auto",
        "border": "none",
        "background-color": "white"
    });
    $("#myMap").css({
        "width": "500px",
        "height": "400px",

    });
    $(".navbar-expand-md .navbar-nav .nav-link").css({
        "padding-right": "4.25rem",
        "padding-left": "4.25rem"
    });
    $("body").css("background-color", localStorage.getItem("default"));
});

$(".box").click(function () {
    var color = $(this).css("background-color");
    var image = "images/logo_"+$(this).attr("id");
   changeColor(image, color)
});



function changeColor(image, color){
    $(".index_top,.about-text,.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link:focus, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .active > .nav-link, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link.active, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link.show, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .show > .nav-link,.navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link:focus, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link:hover, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .active > .nav-link, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link.active, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .nav-link.show, .navbar-dark .navbar-nav .show > .nav-link").css("background-color", color);
     $("#nav").css("border-bottom-color", color);
     $("#logo_img").attr("src", image);
     $(".for-bold-text").css("color", color);  
    localStorage.setItem("default", color);     
}

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use local storage to store values and retrive on page refresh.

```
$("#red").click(function () {
       localStorage.setItem("color","red"); 
    });


  $(document).ready(function () {
    var color= localStorage.getItem("color");   //get from local storage.
        $("#content-width").click(function () {
            $("#content").css({
                "color": color,    // here you use value from local storage. 
                "width": "900px",
                "margin": "auto",
                "border": "1px solid #ddd",
                "background-color": "white"

            });
```

Hope this helps.

More info is available at https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_localstorage.asp

Comment: Are you getting any error? I have added code just to show you how localstorage work in jquery, rest of the logic you have to write. Also I have provided you link to start with. You can get all the details to begin with.

Comment: Did you check console.. try to add console after localsotrage to see what you get from localstorage

Answer (score 0):

If you clear your #color.click function, I think your problem will solve.

```
function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#content-width").click(function () {
        $("#content").css({
            "width": "900px",
            "margin": "auto",
            "border": "1px solid #ddd",
            "background-color": "white"
```